# Xsane: Failed to open device `hpaio:/net/Photosmart_C5100_series?zc=HP5180': Error during device I/O

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp, scanner

Printing from an application works.
The hp-toolbox *sometimes* cannot connect.
And Xsane pops the error message as in the title.
Connected through the network, I can ping the device, I can print to it.

The All-in-one used to work fine a while ago (at least before 12.04).

The output of `hp-check -rt` is as follows:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.12.2)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 14.3

Copyright (c) 2011-14 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz 
or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.                    
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc)  
or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.            
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode will check both of the above cases  
(both compile- and run-time dependencies).                                                                       

Saving output in log file: hp-check.log

Initializing. Please wait...

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

Basic system information:
Linux diablo 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distribution:
ubuntu 12.04

Checking Python version...
OK, version 2.7.3 installed

Checking PyQt 4.x version...
OK, version 4.9.1 installed.

Checking for CUPS...
Status: scheduler is running
warning: Version: (cups-config) Not available. Unable to determine installed version of CUPS.)
error_log is set to level: warn

Checking for dbus/python-dbus...
dbus daemon is running.
python-dbus version: 1.0.0


------------------------
| RUNTIME DEPENDENCIES |
------------------------


Checking for dependency: CUPS - Common Unix Printing System...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: CUPS DDK - CUPS driver development kit...
warning: NOT FOUND! This is an OPTIONAL/RUNTIME ONLY dependency. Some HPLIP functionality may not function properly.

Checking for dependency: GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan)...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: Python XML libraries...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: Python 2.3 or greater - Required for fax functionality...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: Reportlab - PDF library for Python...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: SANE - Scanning library...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: scanimage - Shell scanning program...
OK, found.

Checking for dependency: xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE...
OK, found.


----------------------
| HPLIP INSTALLATION |
----------------------


Currently installed HPLIP version...
HPLIP 3.12.2 currently installed in '/usr/share/hplip'.

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.12.2

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-doc/HTML
icon=no
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv

# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
pp-build=yes
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=yes
foomatic-drv-install=yes
foomatic-ppd-install=yes
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.12.2
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
policy-kit=yes
hpijs-only-build=no
lite-build=no
udev-acl-rules=yes
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
# hplip.state - HPLIP runtime persistent variables. 

[plugin]
installed=0
eula=0



Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[last_used]
device_uri = "hp:/net/Photosmart_C5100_series?zc=HP5180"
printer_name = 
working_dir = .

[settings]
systray_visible = 0
systray_messages = 0

[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%

[refresh]
rate = 30
enable = false
type = 1

[polling]
enable = false
interval = 5
device_list = 

[fax]
voice_phone = 
email_address = 

[installation]
date_time = 06/20/2012 19:48:12
version = 3.12.2



--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------


Photosmart_C5100
----------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/net/Photosmart_C5100_series?zc=HP5180
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/Photosmart_C5100.ppd
PPD Description: HP Photosmart c5100 Series, hpcups 3.11.7
Printer status: printer Photosmart_C5100 is idle.  enabled since Wed 20 Jun 2012 06:13:00 PM CEST
    Processing page 1...
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/net/Photosmart_C5100_series?zc=HP5180
error: unable to open channel
error: Communication status: Failed

printer
-------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: socket://printer:9100
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/printer.ppd
PPD Description: HP Photosmart c5100 Series, hpcups 3.11.7
Printer status: printer printer is idle.  enabled since Wed 20 Jun 2012 06:21:34 PM CEST
    Ready to print.
warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend to function in HPLIP.


----------------------
| SANE CONFIGURATION |
----------------------

'hpaio' in '/etc/sane.d/dll.conf'...
'hpaio' in '/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hplip'...
OK, found. SANE backend 'hpaio' is properly set up.

Checking output of 'scanimage -L'...
device `hpaio:/net/Photosmart_C5100_series?zc=HP5180' is a Hewlett-Packard Photosmart_C5100_series all-in-one


---------------------
| PYTHON EXTENSIONS |
---------------------

Checking 'cupsext' CUPS extension...
OK, found.

Checking 'pcardext' Photocard extension...
OK, found.

Checking 'hpmudext' I/O extension...
OK, found.

Checking 'scanext' SANE scanning extension...
OK, found.



-----------------
| USB I/O SETUP |
-----------------

Checking for permissions of USB attached printers...

HP Device 0x324 at 002:006: 
warning:     Device URI: (Makeuri FAILED)

---------------
| USER GROUPS |
---------------

jhendrix adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare

error: User needs to be member of group 'lp' to enable print, scan & fax.
User member of group 'lpadmin'.

-----------
| SUMMARY |
-----------

error: 3 errors and/or warnings.

Please refer to the installation instructions at:
http://hplip.sourceforge.net/install/index.html


Done.
```

My syslog shows these lines after starting `xsane`:

```
Jun 20 19:53:38 diablo xsane: io/hpmud/jd.c 800: mdns lookup HP5180.local retry 19...
Jun 20 19:53:38 diablo xsane: io/hpmud/jd.c 800: mdns lookup HP5180.local retry 20...
Jun 20 19:53:39 diablo xsane: io/hpmud/jd.c 796: error timeout mdns lookup HP5180.local
Jun 20 19:53:42 diablo xsane: io/hpmud/jd.c 89: unable to read device-id
Jun 20 19:53:53 diablo dbus[1704]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Avahi': timed out
```

Hints/tips anyone to get my scanner working again?

Comment: Manually started Avahi: `sudo /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon start`, now Xsane starts. Not sure why the process died in the first place: `Process 1637 died: No such process; trying to remove PID file. (/var/run/avahi-daemon//pid)`

Answer (score 25):

For anyone coming to this page, like I did, looking to solve this issue. I ended up trying something very simple that worked for me.

My system is Ubuntu 12.10. I have a HP MFP CM1312 network printer.

1. I installed "HPLIP Toolbox" from the Ubuntu software center (I already had HPLIP installed).
2. From a terminal, I ran `sudo hp-plugin`, clicked "Next" through the defaults.

Network scanning worked flawlessly.

Comment: Installing "HPLIP Toolbox" broke down even the basic printing which I was able to do before. I had to then uninstall HPLIP Toolbox and reinstall HPLIP to start printing again!

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.04 and it was sufficient just to install the `hp-plugin`.

Answer (score 17):

```
Failed to open device'hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1136_MFP?serial=0000000000H77VXNPR1a': Error during device I/O.
```

I had the above error when I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. And I found the solution as below:

1. Open the terminal.
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo hp-plugin
   ```
3. Go through the HP installation.

After following these steps you will get no error message.

Comment: As of today, hp-plugin displays a message `warning: It is not recommended to run 'hp-plugin' in a root mode.`. Running it as a simple user worked just fine on my set-up (but it prompts for the root password to complete the installation).

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem. Avahi is running for me. It looks like a general bug in 3.12.6:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1015319

Downgrading to 3.12.4 worked. I got the packages from launchpad here:

https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/hplip/3.12.4-1/

To build the package (from memory, but hopefully it helps):

- Copy the tar.gz files to `/usr/local/src`
- `sudo aptitude build-dep hplip`
- `sudo aptitude install devscripts`
- `tar -xzf hplip_3.12.4.orig.tar.gz`
- `tar -xzf hplip_3.12.4-1.debian.tar.gz`
- `mv debian hplip-3.12.4`
- `cd hplip-3.12.4`
- `debuild -us -uc`
- `cd ..`
- `dpkg -i *.deb`

Here are other references to people having the same problem:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/xsane-failed-to-open-device-4175414927/

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-and-Copying/Problem-with-scanning-Debian-HP-L7590/td-p/1755055

Answer (score 3):

- Install your printer with 'hplip'
- Install 'hplip toolbox' from the software centre
- Open HPLip Toolbox from the Dash.
- On the actions tab, click on 'Install Required Plugin'
- Click through the install.

Now try accessing the scanner using 'Simple Scan' via the Dash. Works flawlessly.

Thanks @Nelson Garcia, although my method is slightly different, your post solved it for me.